# C++ pointers runtime error - setting a variable with pointers then retrieving

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I'm setting up a prototype c++ console application. 
The program contains some virtual classes and pointers etc.
When the program reaches the lines of code below in the main function it crashes. I believe it is something to do with accessing the memory at that pointer.

main()

```
...
Player _player();  //new player object created
Actor *player = &_player;  //pointer to player created

...
//note player and get_inventory() are/return a pointer
{
 Inventory* a =  player->get_Inventory();
 a->set_testMe("testedMe");
 string result = a->get_testMe();
 cout << result << endl;
}

{
 Inventory* a =  player->get_Inventory();
 string result = a->get_testMe();  //This causes error
 cout << result << endl;
}
...
```

Actor.cpp //get_Inventory()

```
...
Inventory* Actor::get_Inventory()
{
    Inventory mInventory = this->actorInventory;
    Inventory * pInventory = &mInventory;
    return pInventory;
}
...
```

Inventory.cpp

```
...
Inventory::Inventory()
{
this->testMe = "initial test";
}

void Inventory::set_testMe(string input)
{
    this->testMe = input;
}
string Inventory::get_testMe()
{
    return this->testMe;
}
...
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: If you split that statement into several steps, like saving the return of `player->get_Inventory()` in a variable, you can more easily check if it's a `nullptr`. Also, can you please show the declaration of the `testMe` variable?

Comment: What does the `get_Inventory()` function do/return

Comment: Show us your testcase.

Comment: are you sure player is not NULL and get_Inventory() is not NULL.  you are not showing enough code to guarantee the pointers are valid.  the Inventory snippets look fine.

Comment: Ok I have split up the first statement in two as suggested. This seemed to work but when trying to retrieve the testMe string again from another block it crashed at runtime again.
I have edited the above code to match.
Give me a min and I will add the other functions too.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried debugging and inspecting the pointers used and returned?

Comment: `Player _player();` declares a function `_player` that returns a `Player` - either change this to `Player _player{};` or simply `Player _player;` to define a variable `_player`

Comment: @melak47 In my original code this is - Player _player(a) where 'a'is a string passed to the constructor. Could this be causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns a pointer to a local variable:

```
Inventory* Actor::get_Inventory()
{ 
    Inventory mInventory = this->actorInventory;
    Inventory * pInventory = &mInventory;
    return pInventory;
}
```

The first statement copies `this->actorInventory` into a local variable (as in, local to the method `get_Inventory`), and then returns a pointer to that local variable.  Once you return from `get_Inventory()`, that variable goes out of scope and no longer exists.

You may want to try returning a pointer to `this->actorInventory` directly:

```
Inventory *Actor::get_Inventory()
{
    return &actorInventory;
}
```

Or, if you don't want the caller modifying `actorInventory`, return a `const` qualified pointer:

```
const Inventory *Actor::get_Inventory() const
{
    return &actorInventory;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks that was exactly it. I thought that seemed like a lot of code to just return a pointer. I initially tried 'return &this->actorInventory; which clearly didnt work.